# How to solve the red line's issue (taskSnapshot)?

Tags: android

How to solve the red line's problem (**taskSnapshots**)

> int progress = (int)((100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) /
>   taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());

What's wrong in that line?

```html
    private void uploadImg(final String path){
        final Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
        StorageMetadata metadata = new StorageMetadata.Builder()
                .setContentDisposition("universe")
                .setContentType("image/jpg")
                .build();
        riversRef = mStorageRef.child(file.getLastPathSegment());
        UploadTask uploadTask = riversRef.putFile(file, metadata);
        uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                uploadInfoText.setText(exception.getMessage());
            }
        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                uploadInfoText.setText(R.string.upload_success);
                Glide.with(NewPostActivity.this)
                        .load(file)
                        .into(downloadImg);

            }
        }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                int progress = (int)((100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                imgUploadProgress.setProgress(progress);
                if(progress >= 100){
                    imgUploadProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Check out there will be certain errors or suggestions provided. Mostly in red bulb on left corner. Click on it. Even again error is not getting resolved then google for it. And google is not able to provide solution then there is a good chance you have not written program properly as required and you are not aware of it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your screenshot, I see that there is a red bulb to the left. Click on that and it should provide with errors and/or suggestions to fix the errors. If you can compile the app and use it, you can disable the inspection using:

```
@SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests")
```